# How to disable the global view/layout object from within a controller in zf2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm using ZF 2.0.6 and I know about the following trick to disable the view, but it leaves other global views/layouts intact. I also know there is a setContent method which clobbers everything which is not what I need. **So how to disable the global view/layout object from within a controller?**

*Disable the view only*

```
$viewModel = new ViewModel(array());
$viewModel->setTerminal(true);
return $viewModel;
```

*Clobber the response*

```
return $this->getResponse()->setContent('Nooooooooo!');
```

There seems to be a problem when setting the layout in the Module bootstrap and dispatch event.

Comment: Sorry Sam thought it was obvious -- and the title was the question -- but i will add it in the content block as well >)

Comment: Just didn't get it i guess ;) What exactly do you want to achieve? There may be a different approach to what you want to do in general that might be better suited that what you're currently trying to do. E.g.: If you need a Controller that displays only Data you may find RestFulController or the JsonModel interesting?

Comment: I know i can output only json but i want to output a generated form in say a modal window without any globl views/layout -- if not i will have to parse json and re-create the generated form -- does that make sense?

Comment: Of course, but especially for that case, the display of a form is content to ONE action of ONE Controller, and therefore your first example `$vM->setTerminal(true)` would be the way to go

Comment: I tried using `setTerminal(true)` and it disabled the form but left the global view/layout -- am i doing something wrong in my configuration maybe

Comment: I also tried to unset or change the layout template and still no go -- wish the documentation addressed this >)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled on the clobber method and passing a new view model. This seems to work but there must be a more elegant method.

*Controller*

```
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Module\Form\Form;

....

public function createAction()
{
    $viewRenderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewrenderer');
    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
    $viewModel->setTemplate('module/controller/action')
              ->setVariables(array('form' => new Form()));
    return $this->getResponse()
                ->setContent($viewRenderer->render($viewModel));
}
```

Comment: This method was needed if you do anything with a view model at the module level, else just use the `setTerminal()` method.

Comment: By anything with the view model I mean things like switching the layout|view based on a route or something.